# Create a matrix to be filled in without specifying its dimension

Tags: r, loops, matrix

I am working on an algorithm in which I perform an action iteratively and in each repetition I obtain a series of values ( a vector). I would like to keep this vector inside a matrix, for instance as a column, but the problem is that I don't know a priori how many iterations will be made by the algorithm. As far as I know, in R you have to specify the dimension of the matrix. 
Any idea of how to solve it?

Comment: take a look at `rbind()` or `cbind()`. You can add new rows/columns in each iteration.

Comment: Possible to use a list and save 1 child per iteration then gather everything once you know the final size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### When vector length is known

Here's a solution where you create an empty matrix `M` of known dimensions (number of rows is vector length (`lVector`) and number of columns (`nCols`) you pick yourself). After `nCols` (when matrix is full) you write it to a disc with a unique identifier.

```
# These parameters are known
lVector <- 10
nCols <- 1e4
# Create matrix
M <- matrix(nrow = lVector, ncol = nCols)
iter <- 0

# This is unknown before
nIterations <- 1e5 + 10

# Perform iterations
for(i in seq_len(nIterations)) {
    iter <- iter + 1

    # Perform simulation and write result to a matrix column
    M[, iter] <- sample(100, 10)

    if (iter == nCols) {
        # Write result to disc
        saveRDS(M, paste0("result_", i, ".RDS"))
        # Reset counter
        iter <- 0
        # Create new empty matrix
        M <- matrix(nrow = lVector, ncol = nCols)
    }
}
# Write last 10 iterations to a disc (they didn't reach 1e4)
saveRDS(M[, 1:iter], paste0("result_", i, ".RDS"))
```

This will write matrices (`result_10000.RDS`, `result_20000.RDS`, ...)

---

### When vector length is unknown

Here you can create an empty list of length `lList` and after `lList` iterations write it to a disc and re-create a new list.

```
# These parameters are known
lList <- 1e4
iter <- 0
# Create empty list
L <- rep(list(NA), lList)

# This is unknown before
nIterations <- 1e5 + 10

# Perform iterations
for(i in seq_len(nIterations)) {
    iter <- iter + 1
    L[[iter]] <- sample(100, 10)
    if (iter == lList) {
        saveRDS(L, paste0("result_", i, ".RDS"))
        iter <- 0
        L <- rep(list(NA), lList)
    }
}
saveRDS(L[1:iter], paste0("result_", i, ".RDS"))
```

Comment: and if we don't know the length of the vector at each iteration? in my case are coefficients obtained in a LASSO regression, so in each step the number of non-zero coefficients may be different.

Comment: @RamiroScorolli Updated my answer. In that case you can use a list.

Answer (score 1):

Create an empty list.
At each iteration, the list has one more element of unknown length.

```
res <- list()
unknown_iterations <- 10
for (k in 1:unknown_iterations){
  res[[length(res) + 1]] <- sample(1:k, k)
}
res
unlist(res)
```

Then you can apply the shape you want to your data.